# Как правильно: "на конверте штамп почты датирован" или ... ?

Tags: лексика

Здравствуйте!

Корректно ли составлено предложение: "На конверте штамп почты датирован 13 августа". Если это некорректно, то как будет правильно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, Ваше предложение лучше перестроить. ***Штамп на конверте датирован 13 августа***. Может быть, так? "На конверте" в этом предложении - несогласованное определение.

Answer (score 0):

Неграмотно, так как "на конверте" - это обстоятельство, а обстоятельства зависят только от сказуемых. Очевидно, что нельзя задать корректный вопрос от слова "датирован", которое в вашем предложении является сказуемым, поэтому можно сказать, что здесь, должно быть, опущено сказуемое "находится". 
Самым грамотным вариантом будет: "На конверте - штамп, датированный 13 августа" (тире появляется ввиду опущенного сказуемого).